# Error: Error creating AWSConfig rule: Failed to create AWSConfig rule: InvalidParameterValueException

Tags: terraform, aws-config

I'm trying to add a an `aws_config_config_rule` resource with a set of `input_parameters`, but I keep getting

```
Error: Error creating AWSConfig rule: Failed to create AWSConfig rule: InvalidParameterValueException: Unknown parameters provided in the inputParameters: {"targetBucket":"mybucket"}.
```

```
# Enables access logging for the CloudTrail S3 bucket
resource aws_config_config_rule cloudtrail-s3-bucket-logging-enabled {
    name = "cloudtrail-s3-bucket-logging-enabled"
    description = "Checks whether logging is enabled for your S3 buckets."

    source {
        owner   = "AWS"
        source_identifier = "S3_BUCKET_LOGGING_ENABLED"
    }

    scope {
        compliance_resource_id = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.arn
        compliance_resource_types = ["AWS::S3::Bucket"]
    }

    input_parameters = jsonencode({"targetBucket":"${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id}"})
}
```

I figured I could use the jsonencode function https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html. I came across a github issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14074, but it is different from what I'm experiencing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong input parameters for this rule. This works

```
# Ensures that the S3 bucket used by CloudTrail is not publicly accessible
resource aws_config_config_rule cloudtrail-s3-bucket-not-publicy-accessible {
    name = "cloudtrail-s3-bucket-not-publicy-accessible"
    description = "Checks whether the required public access block settings are configured from account level. The rule is only NON_COMPLIANT when the fields set below do not match the corresponding fields in the configuration item."

    source {
        owner   = "AWS"
        source_identifier = "S3_ACCOUNT_LEVEL_PUBLIC_ACCESS_BLOCKS"
    }

    scope {
        compliance_resource_id = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id
        compliance_resource_types = ["AWS::S3::Bucket"]
    }
    input_parameters =  "{\"IgnorePublicAcls\":\"True\",\"BlockPublicPolicy\":\"True\",\"BlockPublicAcls\":\"True\",\"RestrictPublicBuckets\":\"True\"}"
}
```